# .load() contents of a div instead of the whole div

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#content').load(href + ' #content');
```

is it possible to load only the contents of `#content` instead of loading the whole `<div id="contents">` so I can prevent having `<div id="contents"><div id="contents"></div></div>`?

I forgot to place wrappers on a lot of pages and it would save me some time if there's a workaround on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try

```
$('#content').load(href + ' #content > *');
```

Note: If `#content` has any text nodes as its children(not descendants) then it may not work(the text nodes may not get copied)

Demo: [Fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/vdiGujhdIsyBvfgSqvKo?p=preview)

---

Another solution is to manually remove the second wrapper, if it exists like

```
$('#content').load('ajax.html' + ' #content', function () {
    if ($(this).children('#content').length) {
        $(this).contents().unwrap()
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/OpKKm3szJq7fnaU80EnN?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Why not stick them somewhere else first then move over what you want

```
$(document.createElement('div')).load(href + ' #content', function (e) {
    var elms = this.firstChild.childNodes,
        parent = document.getElementById('content');
    while (elms.length) {
        parent.appendChild(elms[0]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `load()` method is mostly used to load remote data..

You cannot have two elements with the same ID..

```
$( "#result" ).load( "page.html #desiredContent" );
```

Comment: Im using it to load pages dynamically

Answer (score 0):

The $.load function takes handler for when the request is complete (http://api.jquery.com/load/). So when you request the matched '#content' element from the other page, have the complete function only return the inner html. Something like:

```
$('#content').load(href + ' #content',function(data){ return data.html(); });
```